# Use of Subquery in a query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database which has a number of tables:

- `matters`

  1. `matterid`
  2. `mattername`
  3. `state`
- `matterjuncstaff`

  1. `junked`
  2. `matterid`
  3. `staffid`
- `staff`

  1. `staffid`
  2. `staffname`
  3. `lead` (lead can be either Y or N)
- `matterjunactions`

  1. `matterid`
  2. `actiondate`

**Rules**

- A matter will have a number of staff associated with it but only one lead.
- A matter can have any number of actions associated with it.

I want to extract a table which shows all matters where their `state` is `'Open'` and lists the `matterid`, `mattername`, the `staffname` for the person who is the `lead` on the `matter` (i.e. has `lead='Y'`) and the last `actiondate` for the `matter`.

I have tried various ways of doing this and believe that it can be done using subqueries but I can’t work out the format for getting these into my query.

Comment: Can you please add your table with some dummy data. And expected output. Also paste the query that u have tried.

Comment: Sounds like a group by to me. Select the columns you want to group by, then last column should be max( actiondate).

Comment: format the question properly so that we can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
Select m.matterid, m.mattername, s.staffname, max(actiondate)
From matters m
Inner join matterjuncstaff mjs using (matterid)
Inner join staff s using (staffid)
Inner join matterjunactions mj
 On mj.Matterid = m.matterid
Where m.state = 'open'
And s.lead = 'Y'
Group by m.matterid, m.mattername, s.staffname
```

Comment: Hi @Graham if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: That works fine. Thank you.

I have one other follow up though. The table I want to get looks something like:

mattername | max(actiondate) | staffname |
matterabc | 2015-03-01 | Fred Smith | 

As explained above the staff name is that of anyone with the field ‘lead’ marked as ‘Y’. For some matters there are 2 or 3 lead people and I would like to display them all on one row. So for each matter we would get something like:

mattername | max(actiondate) | staffname |
matterabc | 2015-03-01 | Fred Smith, Sue Jones |

Is there a way I can get that?